# If $A$ is a square matrix of order 3 with $\det(A)=1$ and $AA^\top=I$, prove that $\det(A-I)=0$.

Tags: matrices, determinant

> If $A$ is a square matrix of order 3 with $\det(A)=1$ and $AA^\top=I$, prove that $\det(A-I)=0$.

I tried everything I know but couldn't get to the proof.

Answer (score 2):

$det(A-I)=det(A-AA^\top)=det(A(I-A^\top))=det(I-A^\top)=det(I-A)=(-1)^3det(A-I) \implies det(A-I)=0$

Comment: $det(I-A^T)=det((I-A^T)^T)=det(I-A)$, right?

Comment: Yes you're right

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be proven by matrix calculus, but here's a semi-geometric proof:

We have $A A^T=I$, so $A$ is an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).

$A$ is of order 3, and because its determinant is +1, it must be the [matrix of a rotation in 3D space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions). Therefore it can be put into the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
0 & \sin(\theta) &\cos(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Therefore, $\det(A-I)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$A - I  = A - AA^T$

$\Rightarrow det ( A- I) = det (  A - AA^T ) $

$\Rightarrow det ( A- I) = det (A (I^T - A^T))$

$\Rightarrow$ det (A- I) = det (A)•det$(I^T - A^T)$

$\Rightarrow det ( A- I)$ = 1• (-) det $( A - I )^T$

$\Rightarrow det ( A- I) = (-) det (A - I)$

$\Rightarrow det ( A- I) = 0$

Comment: Did you mean $A-AA^T$ on the second line and "det" on the last?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I've made the required changes.